# Emoji is not stored properly in MySQL 5.6 with collation utf8mb4

Tags: mysql, character-encoding, collation, emoji, utf8mb4

I am trying to store emoji to the database in my server. I am using AWS EC2 instance as server, my server details are listed below:

> OS: ubuntu0.14.04.1
>
> MySQL version: 5.6.19-0ubuntu0.14.04.1 - (Ubuntu)
>
> Database client version: libmysql - mysqlnd 5.0.11-dev - 20120503

I created a database test and table emoji in the server with following SQL:

```
CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS `test` DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_general_ci;
USE `test`;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `emoji` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `text` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
```

When I tried to execute the following insert, a warning appears and data are not stored properly:

```
INSERT INTO  `test`.`emoji` (`id` , `text`) VALUES (NULL ,  '   ');
```

> Inserted row id: 3
>
> Warning: #1366 Incorrect string value: '\xF0\x9F\x91\x86 \xF0...' for column 'text' at row 1

The value stored in the text column is: **???? ???? ???? ????**

The same scenario work for my local database and the values are stored properly. Almost all configurations are similar in my local except the OS (Windows).

Comment: Please do `SHOW CREATE TABLE test.emoji\G` -- I want to see if it got mangled somehow after you created it.

Comment: Wat what prompt did you run the `INSERT` that is failing?  (The F09F9186 looks correct.)

Comment: CREATE TABLE `emoji` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `text` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=4 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4

Comment: Please provide `SELECT text, HEX(text) FROM emoji` (for the row in question).  Something strange is going on.

Comment: Am using drupal for my application. For testing the emoji features, I am using PhpMyAdmin interface, which shows the warning messages also. WHen executing from console, gives the warning as well: `Query OK, 1 row affected, 1 warning (0.00 sec)`

Comment: `1 warning` -- run the query again, then promptly do `SHOW WARNINGS;`

Comment: `+-----------------------------------+---------------------------------------------------+
| text                              | HEX(`text`)                                                     |
+-----------------------------------+---------------------------------------------------+
| ???? ???? ???? ????         | 3F3F3F3F203F3F3F3F203F3F3F3F203F3F3F3F                 +-----------------------------------+--------------------------------------------------------------------+
`

Comment: phpmyadmin and/or drupal may be changing things in mysterious ways.  Which one gave you `????`?  Which one gave you #1366?

Comment: Grrr... The only way I know to get that hex in the table is for the column to be declared `latin1`, which it clearly is not.

Comment: Warning | 1366 | Incorrect string value: '\xF0\x9F\x91\x86 \xF0...' for column 'text' at row 1 |

Comment: What is the charset of the connection?  (Both phpmyadmin and drupal).  Look in the dsn or connection parameters.  Are you connecting as `root`?

Comment: The last warning posted here is from the mysql console

Comment: "mysql console" -- are you referring to the "mysql commandline tool"?

Comment: @RickJames `| Variable_name            | Value                      |
| character_set_client     | utf8                       |
| character_set_connection | utf8                       |
| character_set_database   | utf8mb4                    |
| character_set_filesystem | binary                     |
| character_set_results    | utf8                       |
| character_set_server     | latin1                     |
| character_set_system     | utf8                       |
| character_sets_dir       | /usr/share/mysql/charsets/ |
+--------------------------+----------------------------+
`

Comment: @RickJames Yes, am using mysql command line tool from server SSH connection. The same behavior on phpmyadmin as well.

Comment: it's probably the database connection settings see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35125933/mysql-utf8mb4-errors-when-saving-emojis?rq=1

Answer (score 5):

I was able to recreate your issue using SqlWorkbench.

You're client most likely has established a connection to the db whose character set does not match the character set of the table:

run this statement before you run the insert statement to align the character set and collation of the connection:

```
SET NAMES utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_general_ci
```

Hope this helps,  character sets can be tricky.

Answer (score 0):

Trying to save emoji's in my existing database table using the following stack Node-Js 12.13.x , Mysql 5.6.

Way around:

1. Either follow this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39463134/how-to-store-emoji-character-in-mysql-database#answer-39465494)
2. Or change the column data type to **BLOB** i.e

`ALTER TABLE table_name CHANGE column column BLOB NULL`

Hope this trick will work for you!

Answer (score -1):

Migration from MSSQL to MySQL using workbench always getting problem.

Workbench already sets utf8mb4, and still getting error.

Then i follow @Haisum Usman's suggestion:

1. Set column as Blob on migration sql generated.
2. Migrate data
3. Change column to LONGTEXT!

Lots of time invested to get this working.